# Processing link() returning multiple links

Tags: loops, if-statement, processing

I have a pretty basic scatter plot which shows the largest impact craters on earth. The y-axis is diameter, the x is age.

I am trying to create an interaction where when you click a data point on the graph a link displaying the craters wiki page opens.

I have it working, but when you click the data point a page opens for every entry in the loop. I get a dozen+ of the same page.

Is there a way to make it only return one entry. I tried noLoop(); this works, it only returns the relevant entry, but it stops the program, making it so I can longer click on other data points.

I included relevant code below.

```
int rowNumber; //set rowNumber as an integer
int dataWH = 10; //data width/height
int row = 0; 

Table craterWiki = loadTable("craterWiki.tsv"); //loads and parses tsv data into rows and columns
String craterLink = craterWiki.getString(row, 5);

PFont font;
PFont fontTitle;

void setup() {
  size(1120, 920);
  rowNumber = craterWiki.getRowCount(); //number of rows
  font = loadFont("CourierNewPSMT-14.vlw");
  fontTitle = loadFont("CourierNewPSMT-18.vlw");

}

void draw() {
  background(#111727);
  textFont (font, 14);
  textSize(14); //deafult font size
  stroke(180);
  fill(180, 200);

  int vertx = 45;  // location of y-axis title on x
  int verty = 460; // location of y-axis title on y
  int headx = 560; // location of header on x
  int heady = 50;  // location of header on y
  int infox = 560; // location of crater info on x
  int infoy = 400; // location of crater info on y

  // x-axis setup (crater age)
  textAlign(CENTER);
  line(100, 830, 1024, 830); // x-axis line
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) { // loops x-axis data in 16 increments
  text (i*150, i * 60 + 100, 850); // 16 increments of 150, spacing between    each increment, and location of the chain
  }
   textFont (fontTitle, 18);
   text("Crater Age (million years)", 560, 885);

  // y-axis setup (crater diameter)
  textAlign(CENTER);
  textFont (font, 14);
  line(100, 80, 100, 830); // y-axis line
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) { // loops y-axis data in 16 increments
  text (i*20, 80, 830-i*49); //16 increments of 20, spacing between each   increment, and location of the chain
  }
  pushMatrix(); //reset matrix stack
  translate(vertx,verty); //location of y-axis title
  rotate(-HALF_PI); //make text vertical
  textFont (fontTitle, 18);
  text("Crater Diameter (km)", 0, 0);
  popMatrix();

  pushMatrix(); //reset matrix stack
  translate(headx,heady); //location of header title
  textFont (fontTitle, 18);
  text(" Largest Impact Craters on Earth", 0, 0);
  popMatrix();
  textFont (font, 14);

// data point draw loop
for (int row = 0; row < rowNumber; row++) {

// define/load table again
Table craterWiki = loadTable("craterWiki.tsv");

// crater names displayed above data point and in center 
gString craterName = craterWiki.getString(row, 0);

// crater location displayed in center
String craterLocation = craterWiki.getString(row, 1);

// crater size displayed in center
String craterCountry = craterWiki.getString(row, 2);

String craterLink = craterWiki.getString(row, 5);

// crater size displayed in center
float craterSize = craterWiki.getFloat(row,  3);
float y = map(craterSize, 0, 300, 825, 100);

// crater age displayed in center
float craterAge = craterWiki.getFloat(row, 4);
float x = map(craterAge, 0, 2250, 100, 1024);

// data point ellipse based off of the actual diameter of the crater (craterSize)
noStroke();
fill(#FFBA00, 180);
ellipse(x, y, dataWH*craterSize/45, dataWH*craterSize/45);


// mouse interaction
textAlign(CENTER);
fill(180, 200);

// when mouse is over the craterSize ellipse display the text below
if(dist(x, y, mouseX, mouseY) < (dataWH*craterSize/45))  {
  pushMatrix();
  translate(infox,infoy);
  text( "Crater Name: " + craterName, 0, 0);
  text( "Location: " + craterLocation, 0 , 60);
  text( "Country: " + craterCountry, 0 , 80);
  text( "Age: " + craterAge +" million years", 0 , 40);
  text( "Diameter: " + craterSize + "km", 0 , 20);
  popMatrix();

  //second ellipse is also created when the mouse is over the craterSize ellipse
  int dataWH = 12;
  text(craterName, x, y - dataWH*craterSize/90 - 5);
  fill(#FFD564, 180);
  ellipse(x, y, dataWH*craterSize/45, dataWH*craterSize/45);

  }
 }  
}


// if mouse pressed display crater wiki page

 void mousePressed() { 

 link(craterLink); 
}
```

If more information is required please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You're checking (aka **polling**) whether the mouse is pressed 60 times per second. Instead of polling, you should just use an **event function** that fires just once every time the mouse is clicked:

```
void mousePressed() { 
   link(craterLink); 
}
```

More info on the event functions can be found in the reference [here](https://www.processing.org/reference/mousePressed_.html).

Comment: @user2142912 You're still looping over multiple links and opening a bunch of pages. In the `draw()` function, set your `craterLink` variable. Then just use the code in my answer (maybe with a check for null).

Comment: @user2142912 Yes, see the comment I just posted.

Comment: I think I have to set the variables globally I will try that, and then run it with your code.

Comment: @user2142912 Right, you'd need to declare your `craterLink` variable at the sketch level, so both your `draw()` and `mousePressed()` functions could access it.

Comment: Yeah I get a NullPointerException error when I try to set it globally. I will have to work on this some more.

Comment: @user2142912 Please post your updated code (the code you currently have posted does not have a `draw()` function), and we'll go from there.

Comment: I provided the remainder of my code, the rest of void draw which is just  the graph the points are displayed on, void setup, and global variables.

Comment: @user2142912 You should only be setting the `craterLink` variable **once** in your `draw()` function, or when the user clicks. You need to determine what value the user clicked.